# How to sort round robin tournament with maximum rests per player?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, round-robin

A round robin tournament has `n` players. In each round, all players face each other **once**. Number of games per round is `n * (n-1) / 2`. Number of rounds is unlimited. Games are played one at a time without breaks, so the only way to get rest is to not play consecutive games.

How to find the best order of games with the following goals (in priority order)?

1. Maximize the smallest **length** of rest, i.e. the number of games before the same person plays again
2. Minimize the **count** of smallest rests per round
3. Divide the smallest rests as equally as possible among the players

I didn't figure out any other way to achieve this than the brute-force way: check each possible permutation and keep the best one in memory.

I had 7 people in my scenario. For `n = 7`, the count of games is `7 * 6 / 2 = 21`, meaning that the count of permutations is `21! = 51090942171709440000`. Of course, it's practically impossible to check that many permutations, so I ended up just implementing a program which creates random lists up to `m`. It was enough for my purposes at the time. The best permutation I found with this method (out of 100 million) had 9 one day rests and they were divided pretty equally among different players.

What is the most efficient way to get the best permutation?

For possible code examples I would prefer Java, JavaScript, or Swift.

Comment: Did you implement cyclic-shift round-robin algorithm? Do you know about it?

Comment: I didn't implement any algorithm, I only randomized the order m times and then checked how well the random order satisfies my criteria. After doing this 100 million times, the best result was satisfactory but of course there's probably much better results which weren't discovered.

I don't know about cyclic-shift algorithm. Could you link to some article about it? I didn't find anything related by a quick search.

Comment: Is it only one game at a time?

Comment: Yes, games are sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try random permutations, we can apply a biased random key genetic algorithm (BRKGA). This generic optimization technique can find a solution for n=7 with only four one-match rests, all by different players:

```
1 4 1
1 3
0 4
2 5
1 6
2 3
4 5
0 6
3 5
1 2
4 6
0 3
1 5
2 6
3 4
0 1
2 4
3 6
0 5
1 4
0 2
5 6
```

C++ code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace {

constexpr int kNumPlayers = 7;
constexpr int kNumMatches = kNumPlayers * (kNumPlayers - 1) / 2;

class Solution {
public:
  template <typename Generator> static Solution Random(Generator &generator);

  template <typename Generator>
  Solution MateWith(const Solution &that, Generator &generator) const;

  std::array<std::tuple<int, int>, kNumMatches> Matches() const;

private:
  Solution() = default;

  std::array<double, kNumMatches> keys_;
};

template <typename Generator> Solution Solution::Random(Generator &generator) {
  Solution solution;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform;
  for (int k = 0; k < kNumMatches; k++) {
    solution.keys_[k] = uniform(generator);
  }
  return solution;
}

template <typename Generator>
Solution Solution::MateWith(const Solution &that, Generator &generator) const {
  Solution child;
  std::bernoulli_distribution biased_coin(0.7);
  for (int k = 0; k < kNumMatches; k++) {
    child.keys_[k] = biased_coin(generator) ? this->keys_[k] : that.keys_[k];
  }
  return child;
}

std::array<std::tuple<int, int>, kNumMatches> Solution::Matches() const {
  std::array<std::tuple<double, std::tuple<int, int>>, kNumMatches> rankings;
  {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumPlayers; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < kNumPlayers; j++) {
        rankings[k] = {keys_[k], {i, j}};
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
  std::sort(rankings.begin(), rankings.end());
  std::array<std::tuple<int, int>, kNumMatches> matches;
  for (int k = 0; k < kNumMatches; k++) {
    matches[k] = std::get<1>(rankings[k]);
  }
  return matches;
}

std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>
Rests(const std::array<std::tuple<int, int>, kNumMatches> &matches) {
  std::array<int, kNumMatches> last_match;
  for (int k = 0; k < kNumMatches; k++) {
    last_match[std::get<0>(matches[k])] = k - kNumMatches;
    last_match[std::get<1>(matches[k])] = k - kNumMatches;
  }
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> rests;
  for (int k = 0; k < kNumMatches; k++) {
    auto plays = [&](int i) {
      rests.push_back({k - 1 - last_match[i], i});
      last_match[i] = k;
    };
    plays(std::get<0>(matches[k]));
    plays(std::get<1>(matches[k]));
  }
  return rests;
}

std::tuple<int, int, int>
Objective(const std::array<std::tuple<int, int>, kNumMatches> &matches) {
  auto rests = Rests(matches);
  int min_rest = std::get<0>(*std::min_element(rests.begin(), rests.end()));
  std::array<int, kNumPlayers> player_to_min_rest_count;
  std::fill(player_to_min_rest_count.begin(), player_to_min_rest_count.end(),
            0);
  for (auto [rest, player] : rests) {
    if (rest == min_rest) {
      player_to_min_rest_count[player]++;
    }
  }
  return {-min_rest,
          std::accumulate(player_to_min_rest_count.begin(),
                          player_to_min_rest_count.end(), 0),
          *std::max_element(player_to_min_rest_count.begin(),
                            player_to_min_rest_count.end())};
}

std::vector<Solution> SortByFitness(const std::vector<Solution> &population) {
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int, int>, const Solution *>> tagged;
  tagged.reserve(population.size());
  for (const Solution &solution : population) {
    tagged.push_back({Objective(solution.Matches()), &solution});
  }
  std::sort(tagged.begin(), tagged.end());
  std::vector<Solution> sorted_population;
  sorted_population.reserve(population.size());
  for (auto [objective, solution] : tagged) {
    sorted_population.push_back(*solution);
  }
  return sorted_population;
}

template <typename Generator> Solution BRKGA(Generator &generator) {
  static constexpr int kRounds = 20000;
  static constexpr int kNumEliteSolutions = 300;
  static constexpr int kNumMatedSolutions = 600;
  static constexpr int kNumRandomSolutions = 100;
  static constexpr int kNumSolutions =
      kNumEliteSolutions + kNumMatedSolutions + kNumRandomSolutions;
  std::vector<Solution> population;
  population.reserve(kNumSolutions);
  for (int i = 0; i < kNumSolutions; i++) {
    population.push_back(Solution::Random(generator));
  }
  for (int r = 0; r < kRounds; r++) {
    population = SortByFitness(population);
    std::vector<Solution> new_population;
    new_population.reserve(kNumSolutions);
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumEliteSolutions; i++) {
      new_population.push_back(population[i]);
    }
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> elite(0, kNumEliteSolutions - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> non_elite(kNumEliteSolutions,
                                                 kNumSolutions - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumMatedSolutions; i++) {
      int j = elite(generator);
      int k = non_elite(generator);
      new_population.push_back(
          population[j].MateWith(population[k], generator));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumRandomSolutions; i++) {
      new_population.push_back(Solution::Random(generator));
    }
    population = std::move(new_population);
  }
  return SortByFitness(population)[0];
}

void PrintSolution(const Solution &solution) {
  auto matches = solution.Matches();
  auto objective = Objective(matches);
  std::cout << -std::get<0>(objective) << ' ' << std::get<1>(objective) << ' '
            << std::get<2>(objective) << '\n';
  for (auto [i, j] : solution.Matches()) {
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';
  }
}

} // namespace

int main() {
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  PrintSolution(BRKGA(generator));
}
```

Comment: Would this kind of algorithm work also if there were unlimited rounds? In that case, player 5 would have two consecutive games (last and first).

Answer (score 1):

There is rather simple algorithm to generate all pairs:

Put players in two rows. At every round top player meets corresponding one from lower row. If number of players is odd, one player has the rest.

```
A B C
D E F
A:D B:E C:F
```

After the round shift all but the first player in cyclic manner

```
A D B
E F C
A:E D:F B:C 

A E D
F C B
A:F E:C D:B
...
```

Note if we use game order above (pair left to right), the same player doesn't take part in two subsequent games (except for small number case)

Seems that for `2*N` players the smallest rest is `N-1` (and the longest is `N+1`):

```
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
AG BH CI DJ EK FL 

A G B C D E 
H I J K L F 
AH GI BJ CK DL EF
```

Comment: This seems to be a good way to match up the pairs. However, it’s not the best according to my 2nd criteria. For n = 7, the smallest rest is 1 day but the count of those is 10. I was able to get to 9 just by trying random orders. Good thing is that this method does divide the rests more equally among the players than a random order. Each player has a maximum of 2 single day rests.